# Как правильно перенести шаблон из HTML во Vue.component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, табличная-верстка

День добрый.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
js файл фетчит данные с локального порта, и  я вывожу это дело на странице.

js:

```
//Забираем json из '/receive/', парсим его в gridData 
var gridData = new Vue({
  el: '#gridData',
  data: {
       orders: []
  },
  created:function() {
              let that = this; // The real this
              fetch('/receive/')    
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(res => {
                this.orders = res;
          });

  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gridData" class="gridData" style="width: 100%">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Статус </th>
                    <th>Номер </th>
                    <th>Магазин</th>
                    <th>Дата создания заказа</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="column in orders">
                    <td>{{column.status}}</td>
                    <td>{{column.order_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{column.store_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{column.date_created}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
    </div>
```

И все отлично отображается на странице:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возникла необходимость сделать вторую таблицу на основе этих же данных.

пытаюсь создать vue.component, но кроме имен столбцов ничего не выводится. Прошу помочь, как все правильно оформить.

Последний код, который не выдает ошибки, но данные в столбцы не выводит:

```
 var myTable = Vue.component('my-table', {
    template: `<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Статус заказа</th>
        <th>Номер заказа</th>
        <th>Магазин</th>
        <th>Дата создания заказа</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="key in order">
        <td>{{key.status}}</td>
        <td>{{key.status}}</td>
        <td>{{key.status}}</td>
        <td>{{key.status}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`,
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      orders: []
    }
  },
  props : ['order']

  });

var gridData = new Vue({
  el: '#gridData',
  data: {

      orders: []
  },
  created:function() {
              let that = this; // The real this
              fetch('/receive/')    
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(res => {
                this.orders = res;
          });
      },
  components: {myTable: myTable},
  ready : function(){

  }
});
```

Comment: Возможно, потому что у вас опечатка. Вы заполняете свойство `orders`, а используете `order`.

Comment: Куда же тут запихнуть вторую таблицу?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko нет, пробовал уже.

Comment: @RomanC никуда. просто надо правильно создать компонент. Для следующей таблицы, новый.

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема, бери компонент и создавай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запихнул fetch во Vue.component, и все заработало.

```
var gridData = new Vue({
  el: '#showOrdersData',
  data: {
      orders: []
  },
  components: {ordersTable: ordersTable},
});
```